# Rounding numbers in R to specified number of digits

Tags: r, rounding

I have a problem in rounding numbers in R. I have the following data, and I want to round them to 8 decimal digits.

```
structure(c(9.50863385275955e-05, 4.05702267762077e-06, 2.78921491976249e-05, 
8.9107773737659e-05, 5.0672643927135e-06, 5.87776809485182e-05,
2.76421630542694e-05, 5.51662570625727e-05, 2.52790624570593e-05, 
2.00407457671806e-05, 8.33373482160056e-05, 7.8297940825207e-05,
2.00407457671806e-05, 8.33373482160056e-05, 7.8297940825207e-05,
2.00407457671806e-05, 8.33373482160056e-05, 7.8297940825207e-05
), .Names = c("CC/CC", "TT/CC", "CT/CC", "NC/CC", "CC/TT", "TT/TT",
"CT/TT", "NC/TT", "CC/CT", "TT/CT", "CT/CT", "NC/CT"))
```

These digits are in the form of exponent and I want to convert them to rational numbers with 8 decimal places.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For fine control over formatting of numbers, try `formatC()`

```
res <- structure(c(9.50863385275955e-05, 4.05702267762077e-06), 
                 .Names = c("CC/CC", "TT/CC"))

formatC(res, format="f", digits=8)
```

Comment: Only draw back is the output is a character. So as.numeric() as a wrapper to the format statement is usually needed.

Comment: But you can't control how `numeric`s are displayed. `as.numeric(formatC(9.50863385275955e-05, format = "f", digits = 8))` displays as `9.509e-05` on my system, which is explicitly not what was desired.

Comment: @MichaelHoffman - you can alter this behaviour with `options(scipen = XXX)` where larger numbers for XXX print more decimals.

Answer (score 6):

The `signif` function rounds to a specific number of significant digits (and the `round` function rounds to a specific number of decimals).

```
res <- structure(c(9.50863385275955e-05, 4.05702267762077e-06), 
             .Names = c("CC/CC", "TT/CC"))
signif(res, digits=8)
```

Note that *printing* the result depends on an option, `options(digits=7)`... You can also directly specify the `digits` argument to `print`:

```
print(pi, digits=3)  # 3.14
print(pi, digits=17) # 3.1415926535897931
```

Here's an example illustrating the difference between `signif` and `round`:

```
x <- c(pi, pi*1000, pi/1000)
round(x, 3) # 3.142 3141.593 0.003
signif(x, 3) # 3.14e+00 3.14e+03 3.14e-03
```