# `round()` to many digits in R

Tags: r, rounding

I am using the `round()` function that, according to the help

> rounds the values in its first argument to the specified number
>   of decimal places (default 0).

And the `digits` argument in `round(x, digits = 0)` is an

> integer indicating the number of decimal places (round) .

Could someone explain this output? Because it does not seem to work as advertised. But perhaps I just overlooked something.

```
> round(x = 234234.3456789, digits = 0)
[1] 234234
> round(x = 234234.3456789, digits = 1)
[1] 234234.3
> round(x = 234234.3456789, digits = 2)
[1] 234234.4
> round(x = 234234.3456789, digits = 3)
[1] 234234.3
> round(x = 234234.3456789, digits = 4)
[1] 234234.3
> round(x = 234234.3456789, digits = 5)
[1] 234234.3
> round(x = 234234.3456789, digits = 6)
[1] 234234.3
> round(x = 234234.3456789, digits = 7)
[1] 234234.3
```

I tried changing the number and it seems it is not rounding to the number of decimal places indicated by digits (as indicated), but rather to the total number of places indicated by the argument digits

```
>     round(x = 34.3456789, digits = 0)
[1] 34
>     round(x = 34.3456789, digits = 1)
[1] 34.3
>     round(x = 34.3456789, digits = 2)
[1] 34.35
>     round(x = 34.3456789, digits = 3)
[1] 34.346
>     round(x = 34.3456789, digits = 4)
[1] 34.3457
>     round(x = 34.3456789, digits = 5)
[1] 34.34568
>     round(x = 34.3456789, digits = 6)
[1] 34.34568
>     round(x = 34.3456789, digits = 7)
[1] 34.34568
```

That's weird to me. But again, maybe I am just doing something wrong.

Trying to find an explanation I found [this other question here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681756/rounding-numbers-in-r-to-specified-number-of-digits) and one of the examples there actually seems to work as I expected.

```
x <- c(pi, pi*1000, pi/1000)

> round(x, digits = 0)
[1]    3 3142    0
> round(x, digits = 1)
[1]    3.1 3141.6    0.0
> round(x, digits = 2)
[1]    3.14 3141.59    0.00
> round(x, digits = 3)
[1]    3.142 3141.593    0.003
> round(x, digits = 3)
[1]    3.142 3141.593    0.003
> round(x, digits = 4)
[1]    3.1416 3141.5927    0.0031
> round(x, digits = 5)
[1]    3.14159 3141.59265    0.00314
> round(x, digits = 6)
[1]    3.141593 3141.592654    0.003142
> round(x, digits = 7)
[1]    3.1415927 3141.5926536    0.0031416
```

But when I try doing something similar with my original example, it does not work. Actually, something as similar as `x <- c(pi, pi, pi)`, instead of `x <- c(pi, pi*1000, pi/1000)` does not work (note the last two, it does not add another decimal place, rather it sort of cuts on 7 positions overall).

```
x <- c(pi, pi, pi)
> round(x, digits = 0)
[1] 3 3 3
> round(x, digits = 1)
[1] 3.1 3.1 3.1
> round(x, digits = 2)
[1] 3.14 3.14 3.14
> round(x, digits = 3)
[1] 3.142 3.142 3.142
> round(x, digits = 3)
[1] 3.142 3.142 3.142
> round(x, digits = 4)
[1] 3.1416 3.1416 3.1416
> round(x, digits = 5)
[1] 3.14159 3.14159 3.14159
> round(x, digits = 6)
[1] 3.141593 3.141593 3.141593
> round(x, digits = 7)
[1] 3.141593 3.141593 3.141593
```

I checks object class and structure, and seems the same.

What is going on here?

Comment: In `round()`, `digits` gives the number of decimal places, not the number of significant digits. (Use `signif()` for the latter.) Your examples show that it does exactly this. In addition, when you print numbers, only a limited number of digits is printed. Therefore, you don't get more than one decimal digit when rounding `234234.3456789`. Use `options(digits = 15)` to print more digits.

Comment: The second answer in your link has the exact solution used here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `round` IS working correctly:

```
a <- round(x = 234234.3456789, digits = 7)
paste(a)
[1] "234234.3456789"
```

In your example, `print.default`, which is what happens when you ask R to `print` something is cutting the number of digits.

```
print.default(a, digits = 15)
[1] 234234.3456789
```

You can control the behavoiour via `options`

```
options(digits = 15)
round(pi, digits = 15)
[1] 3.14159265358979
```

Comment: Well,  Stibu's comment was much faster...