# Increasing the digits in mtable() results for comparing models

Tags: r, rounding

With *mtable* under [memsic package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memisc/index.html) if I get the following results for evaluating 2 multiple regression models:

```
                                 Model1                Model2
...
...
...
---------------------------------------------------------------

  sigma                             4.7                   4.7  
  R-squared                         0.5                   0.5  
  F                               306.2                 435.5  
  p                                 0.0                   0.0  
  Deviance                      28907.0               28924.0  
  N                               13236                 13236   
===============================================================
```

Is there a way to increase the digits after decimals?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding numbers in R to specified number of digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681756/rounding-numbers-in-r-to-specified-number-of-digits)